# Javascript map over two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays:

```
const people = [{id:1, name:"John"}, {id:2, name:"Alice"}];
const address = [{id:1, peopleId: 1, address: "Some street 1"}, {id:2, peopleId: 2, address: "Some street 2"}]
```

How can I filter over this two arrays and get one like this:

```
const fullData = [{id: 1, name: "John", address: "Some street 1"}, {id: 2, name: "Alice", address: "Some street 2"}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 18):

**You can try this.**

With the help of `map()` and `find()`

```js
const people = [{id:1, name:"John"}, {id:2, name:"Alice"}];
const address = [{id:1, peopleId: 1, address: 'Some street 1'}, {id:2, peopleId: 2, address: 'Some street 2'}]

let op = people.map((e,i)=>{
  let temp = address.find(element=> element.id === e.id)
  if(temp.address) {
    e.address = temp.address;
  }
  return e;
})
console.log(op);
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I think the matcher in `address` is `peopleId`, whereas `id` is just the address row identifier.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides well id is meant to be used in that way. don't know how op has used.

Comment: What if a person doesn't have an address? Your `map` will throw a TypeError, no?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides op didn't asked.anyways added a check for that.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```js
const persons = [{id:1, name: 'John'}, {id:2, name: 'Alice'}]

const addresses = [{id:1, peopleId: 1, address: 'Some street 1'}, {id:2, peopleId: 2, address: 'Some street 2'}]

const result = persons.map(person => {
  const addressItem = addresses.find(address => address.peopleId === person.id)
  
  person.address = addressItem 
  ? addressItem.address
  : null
  
  return person
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

How to map two address with peopleId 2

```
const persons = [{id:1, name: 'John'}, {id:2, name: 'Alice'}]

const addresses = [{id:1, peopleId: 1, address: 'Some street 1'}, {id:2, peopleId: 2, address: 'Some street 2'},{id:3, peopleId: 2, address: 'Some street 3'}]

const result = persons.map(person => {
  const addressItem = addresses.find(address => address.peopleId === person.id)
  
  person.address = addressItem 
  ? addressItem.address
  : null
  
  return person
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to do that,

```js
const people = [{id:1, name:"John"}, {id:2, name:"Alice"}];
const address = [{id:1, peopleId: 1, address: 'Some street 1'}, {id:2, peopleId: 2, address: 'Some street 2'}]


const res = people.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const index = address.findIndex(item => item.peopleId === curr.id);
  if(index > -1) {
    curr.address = address[index].address;
  }
  
  acc.push(curr);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```